# Displaying JS/HTML Button State/Status when using promises?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to control the state or status of a button that fetches some data from an endpoint, where the return time is unknown or could possibly timeout.

My button is a typical HTML `<button>` that calls a function using `onclick='doWork();'`

I have classes defined for the default state (submit), when clicked (loading), and when complete (completed).

I have to use this Request API (https://developers.freshsales.io/docs/request-api/) to call my endpoint.

**Request API Example:**

```
client.request.get("URL", options)
  .then(
    function(data) {
      //handle "data"
      //"data" is a json string with status, headers, and response.
    },
    function(error) {
      //handle failure
    }
  );
```

**Approach**

- My approach is to set the button to a *loading* state in `doWork();`
- Swapping the classes in `function(data)` on the return of the promise, or swapping the classes on the return of `function(error)`

Sample Code:

```
function doWork(){
 $('#btnSave').addClass('loading');
 client.request.get("URL", options)
  .then(
    function(data) {
       $('#btnSave').removeClass('loading');
       $('#btnSave').addClass('completed');
      // do other stuff
    },
    function(error) {
       $('#btnSave').removeClass('loading');
       $('#btnSave').addClass('failed');
       // do some other stuff
    }
  );
}
```

**Questions**

- Is there an easier way to do this? This seems like a common use case
- Is there any advantage of chaining and handling the button state after the initial `then()` returns, handling state in `.request.get.then().then(//Handle button state here)`?
- Would resetting the button in a `.catch()` prevent the user from being trapped in a loading state, or would I be better served by some sort of timeout to reset the button?

I'm still getting the hanging of promises, so any insights to help me learn a bit more are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using is fine and there is no need to chain as you only have one async call.Chaining is useful when you are dealing with multiple async calls.

As for the third question, I do not understand where you are going to use catch as your Request API (https://developers.freshsales.io/docs/request-api/) has no support for it(atleast not as per the documentation). Also you can handle the request timeout inside the callback function for error like this :

```
    function doWork(){
     $('#btnSave').addClass('loading');
     client.request.get("URL", options)
     .then(
      function(data) {
         $('#btnSave').removeClass('loading');
         $('#btnSave').addClass('completed');
         // do other stuff
      },
      function(error) {
         if(error.status == 504){
           console.log('request timeout');
           //do whatever you want
         }
         $('#btnSave').removeClass('loading');
         $('#btnSave').addClass('failed');
         // do some other stuff
      }
     );
     }
```

Also you won't be stuck in the loading state for a long time since the request timeout mentioned in the documentation is '6 secs' by default. If the request is timed out, the error callback will handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new with promises too, but I think you're doing it just fine.
What you can probably do to have a better syntax would be storing the button in a variable and maybe change the class ('completed' or 'failed') with a function.

Your code would look like :

```js
function doWork(){
 let btn = $(#'btnsave');
 btn.addClass('loading');

 client.request.get("URL", options)
  .then(
    function(data) {
       finishBtnLoading(btn, 'completed')
      // do other stuff
    },
    function(error) {
       finishBtnLoading(btn, 'failed')
       // do some other stuff
    }
  );
}

function finishBtnLoading(btn, newClass) {
 btn.removeClass('loading');
 btn.addClass(newClass);
}
```

As I said I'm new to promises but your code looks exactly like something I could write but if someone with better skill/experience has some tips I would love to read them !